# Updating state on props change in React Form

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble with a React form and managing the state properly. I have a time input field in a form (in a modal). The initial value is set as a state variable in `getInitialState`, and is passed in from a parent component. This in itself works fine.

The problem comes when I want to update the default start_time value through the parent component. The update itself happens in the parent component through `setState start_time: new_time`. However in my form, the default `start_time` value never changes, since it is only defined once in `getInitialState`.

I have tried to use `componentWillUpdate` to force a change in state through `setState start_time: next_props.start_time`, which did actually work, but it gave me `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` errors.

So my question is, what's the correct way of updating state in this case? Am I thinking about this wrong somehow?

Current Code:

```
@ModalBody = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    start_time: @props.start_time.format("HH:mm")

  #works but takes long and causes:
  #"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
  componentWillUpdate: (next_props, next_state) ->
    @setState(start_time: next_props.start_time.format("HH:mm"))

  fieldChanged: (fieldName, event) ->
    stateUpdate = {}
    stateUpdate[fieldName] = event.target.value
    @setState(stateUpdate)

  render: ->
    React.DOM.div
      className: "modal-body"
      React.DOM.form null,
        React.createElement FormLabelInputField,
          type: "time"
          id: "start_time"
          label_name: "Start Time"
          value: @state.start_time
          onChange: @fieldChanged.bind(null, "start_time")

@FormLabelInputField = React.createClass
  render: ->
    React.DOM.div
      className: "form-group"
      React.DOM.label
        htmlFor: @props.id
        @props.label_name + ": "
      React.DOM.input
        className: "form-control"
        type: @props.type
        id: @props.id
        value: @props.value
        onChange: @props.onChange
```

Answer (score 318, accepted):

> > componentWillReceiveProps is depcricated since react 16: use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) instead

If I understand correctly, you have a parent component that is passing `start_time` down to the `ModalBody` component which assigns it to its own state? And you want to update that time from the parent, not a child component.

[React has some tips on dealing with this scenario.](https://web.archive.org/web/20170101062930/http://reactjs.cn/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) (Note, this is an old article that has since been removed from the web. Here's a link to the current [doc on component props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)).

> Using props to generate state in `getInitialState` often leads to duplication of "source of truth", i.e. where the real data is. This is because `getInitialState` is only invoked when the component is first created.
>
> Whenever possible, compute values on-the-fly to ensure that they don't get out of sync later on and cause maintenance trouble.

Basically, whenever you assign parent's `props` to a child's `state` the render method isn't always called on prop update. You have to invoke it manually, using the `componentWillReceiveProps` method.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // You don't have to do this check first, but it can help prevent an unneeded render
  if (nextProps.startTime !== this.state.startTime) {
    this.setState({ startTime: nextProps.startTime });
  }
}
```

Comment: What if you want to do "And you want to update that time from the parent, not a child component." the other way around?

Comment: Then it would be a simple `setState()` within the child component.. unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi, it looks like the link in this answer is broken.

Comment: But what about initial render? componentWillReceiveProps doesn't fire on initial render according to https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: @John you're right, you would just initiate your state in the constructor with the desired props.

Comment: Deprecated as of React 16

Comment: @dude What is deprecated? This code still works in React 16.

Comment: @poepje See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: @dude It's not deprecated yet, what you refer to is just a heads up for future reference. I quote `[..]going to be deprecated in the future`

Comment: @poepje It may not be deprecated yet, but it is viewed as unsafe by the current standard and should probably be avoided

Comment: So, what should be the new way of doing this after componentWillReceiveProps was deprecated?

Comment: Definitely will be deprecated with version 17 as for the warnings implemented in 16.9

Comment: @Boris Now the react team is basically telling you to get stuffed. They give you a new method, called getDerivedStateFromProps. The catch is that this is a static method. Meaning you can't do anything asynchronous to update the state (because you have to return the new state immediately), neither can you access class methods or fields. You can also use memoization, but that does not fit every use case. Once again, the react team wants to force down their way of doing things. It's an extremely stupid and incapacitating design decision.

Comment: `Object.assign({}, oldObj,  newObj)`

Comment: @BorisBasalla [This newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56497386/8331815) should now probably be the accepted one with the new react style

Comment: if you say something is "going to be deprecated" is pretty much already deprecated for all intents and purposes

Comment: use `componentDidUpdate`

Answer (score 93):

Apparently things are changing.... [getDerivedStateFromProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) is now the preferred function.

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, current_state) {
    if (current_state.value !== props.value) {
      return {
        value: props.value,
        computed_prop: heavy_computation(props.value)
      }
    }
    return null
  }
}
```

[(above code by danburzo @ github )](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/721)

Comment: FYI, you need to return also `null` if nothing should change so right after your if, you should go with `return null`

Comment: @IlgıtYıldırım - have edited code since 4 people have upvoted your comment - does it really make a difference?

Comment: There is a pretty good resource that goes in depth on different options and why you would use either `getDerivedStateFromProps` or memoization https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps is forced to be static. Meaning you can't do anything asynchronous to update the state, neither can you access class methods or fields. Once again, the react team wants to force down their way of doing things. It's an extremely stupid and incapacitating design decision.

Answer (score 64):

`componentWillReceiveProps` is being deprecated because using it "often leads to bugs and inconsistencies".

**If something changes from the outside, consider resetting the child component entirely with [`key`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key)**.

Providing a `key` prop to the child component makes sure that whenever the value of `key` changes from the outside, this component is re-rendered. E.g.,

```
<EmailInput
  defaultEmail={this.props.user.email}
  key={this.props.user.id}
/>
```

On its performance:

> While this may sound slow, **the performance difference is usually insignificant.** Using a key can even be faster if the components have heavy logic that runs on updates since diffing gets bypassed for that subtree.

Comment: The key, the secret! Works perfectly in React 16 as mentioned above

Comment: key won't work, if it's an object and your don't have a unique string

Comment: Key does work for objects, I did it. Of course I had a unique string for key though.

Comment: @user3468806 If it is not a complex object with external references, you can use `JSON.stringify(myObject)` to derive a unique key from your object.

Comment: Even if the `key` changes, it will *not* trigger `componentDidMount`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's recommended by [the docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key). If you don't like the key, there's still [ID prop](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#alternative-1-reset-uncontrolled-component-with-an-id-prop) and [instance method](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#alternative-2-reset-uncontrolled-component-with-an-instance-method) reset alternatives.

Answer (score 49):

The new hooks way of doing this is to use useEffect instead of componentWillReceiveProps the old way:

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // You don't have to do this check first, but it can help prevent an unneeded render
  if (nextProps.startTime !== this.state.startTime) {
    this.setState({ startTime: nextProps.startTime });
  }
}
```

becomes the following in a functional hooks driven component:

```
// store the startTime prop in local state
const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(props.startTime)
// 
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.startTime !== startTime) {
    setStartTime(props.startTime);
  }
}, [props.startTime]);
```

we set the state using setState, using useEffect we check for changes to the specified prop, and take the action to update the state on change of the prop.

Comment: Isnt this an anti pattern : https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state ?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Follows the pattern perfectly.

Comment: but what about the class components ?

Comment: @HaveAGuess The first example, probably, but the hook version doesn't have that issue

Comment: This doesn't seem right, is it? It will work, but `useEffect` runs after the page is rendered. Instead, ideally, you'd update the state before the page is rendered.

Answer (score 36):

There is also [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) available.

Function signature:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)
```

Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. Doesn't get called on initial `render`.

See [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) Article, which describes Anti-Pattern for both `componentDidUpdate` and `getDerivedStateFromProps`. I found it very useful.

Comment: I end up using `componentDidUpdate` because it's simple and it's more suitable for most cases.

Comment: Im confused because the article you shared says don't take this approach use a key to invalidate the component?

Comment: See the closing, 'If each value has a clear source of truth, you can avoid the anti-patterns mentioned above'.
It generally says, if you end up with checking `props` and `prevProps` in `didUpdate` there might be a better solution if you rethink dataflow and hierarchy.

Answer (score 12):

[You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)

**1. Set a key from the parent**

> When a key changes, React will create a new component instance rather
>   than update the current one. Keys are usually used for dynamic lists
>   but are also useful here.

**2. Use `getDerivedStateFromProps` / `componentWillReceiveProps`**

> If key doesn’t work for some reason (perhaps the component is very expensive to initialize)

By using `getDerivedStateFromProps` you can reset any part of state but it seems 
 a little buggy at this time (v16.7)!, see [the link above](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) for the usage

Answer (score 7):

```js
// store the startTime prop in local state
const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(props.startTime)
// 
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.startTime !== startTime) {
    setStartTime(props.startTime);
  }
}, [props.startTime]);
```

Can this method be migrated to class components？

Answer (score 4):

From react documentation : https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

> Erasing state when props change is an Anti Pattern

Since React 16, componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated. From react documentation, the recommended approach in this case is use

1. Fully controlled component: the `ParentComponent` of the `ModalBody` will own the `start_time` state. This is not my prefer approach in this case since i think the modal should own this state.
2. Fully uncontrolled component with a key: this is my prefer approach. An example from react documentation : https://codesandbox.io/s/6v1znlxyxn . You would fully own the `start_time` state from your `ModalBody` and use `getInitialState` just like you have already done. To reset the `start_time` state, you simply change the key from the `ParentComponent`

Comment: For people reading this in 2020+ or React 17+, read the link, specifically the section "Recommendation: Fully uncontrolled component with a key ", which is what is suggested here as option #2.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but if anyone wants to achieve this with hooks, here's one.

lib.ts

```
const useSyncedState = <T extends unknown>(initialValue: T) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(initialValue);
    console.log("synced state", initialValue);
  }, [initialValue]);
  return [value, setValue] as const;
};
```

SomeComponent.ts

```
const [myThing, setMyThing = useSyncedState(props.myThing);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite clearly from their docs:

```
If you used componentWillReceiveProps for re-computing some data only when a prop changes, use a memoization helper instead.
```

Use: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization

Answer (score 0):

**Use Memoize**

The op's derivation of state is a direct manipulation of props, with no true derivation needed. In other words, if you have a prop which can be utilized or transformed directly there is **no need to store the prop on state**.

Given that the state value of  `start_time` is simply the prop `start_time.format("HH:mm")`, the information contained in the prop is already in itself sufficient for updating the component.

However if you did want to only call format on a prop change, the correct way to do this per latest documentation would be via Memoize:
https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization

Answer (score 0):

The data source of the form must be based on user input, in the case that the user has entered, any situation resulting in the update of the subcomponent, will trigger componentWillReceiveProps or getDerivedStateFromProps operation, at this time, the value after comparison is certainly not equal, after the execution of setState, the value of the user input will be changed, is not this a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `key` prop to your component with `start_time` as value. React will think of the component as a new, separate one each time you pass a different key.

In your example:

```
  render: ->
    React.DOM.div
      className: "modal-body"
      React.DOM.form null,
        React.createElement FormLabelInputField,
          type: "time"
          id: "start_time"
          label_name: "Start Time"
          value: @state.start_time
          key: @state.start_time
          onChange: @fieldChanged.bind(null, "start_time")
```

Here's a link to React's (beta) docs where this solution is discussed:
[Preserving and Resetting State](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-1-rendering-a-component-in-different-positions)

Answer (score -1):

I think use ref is safe for me, dont need care about some method above.

```
class Company extends XComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.data = {};
    }
    fetchData(data) {
        this.resetState(data);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Input ref={c => this.data['name'] = c} type="text" className="form-control" />
        );
    }
}
class XComponent extends Component {
    resetState(obj) {
        for (var property in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && typeof this.data[property] !== 'undefined') {
                if ( obj[property] !== this.data[property].state.value )
                    this.data[property].setState({value: obj[property]});
                else continue;
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this response is cryptic (code is hardly readable and without any explanation/linking to OP's problem) and does not tackle OP's, problem, which is how to handle initial state.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with the Following solution using Functional Components and the useEffect hook:
It works by having the useEffect hook watch the controlling property from props

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React

const Child = (props) => {
    const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState(props.bgColor);
    const { children } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        setBgColor(props.bgColor);
    }, [props.bgColor]);

    return (
        <div style={{ height: "100px", width: "100px", backgroundColor: bgColor }}>{children}</div>
    )
}

const Parent = (props) => {
    const [childControllingProp, setChildControllingProp] = useState(props.childControllingProp);
    const { title } = props;
    const inputRef = React.createRef();

    return (
        <>
            <input ref={inputRef} type="text" onChange={() => setChildControllingProp(inputRef.current.value)}/>
            <Child bgColor={childControllingProp}>{title}</Child>
        </>
    )
}

$(document).ready(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Parent title="Title" childControllingProp="blue"/>,
        document.querySelector("#root")
    );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```