# ReactJS CSS - how do I re-trigger a @keyframes CSS animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a component that switches some content and the animation of the content depending on the side it is switching it from:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Skills extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      shownSkill: 0,
      fallIn: true,
      slideUp: false
    };
  }

  getPreviousSkill = () => {
    const { shownSkill } = this.state;
    const newSkill = shownSkill < 1 ? 3 : shownSkill - 1;
    this.updateShownSkill(newSkill, false);
  };

  getNextSkill = () => {
    const { shownSkill } = this.state;
    const newSkill = shownSkill > 2 ? 0 : shownSkill + 1;
    this.updateShownSkill(newSkill, true);
  };

  updateShownSkill = (skillIndex, fallIn) => {
    this.setState({
      shownSkill: skillIndex,
      fallIn: fallIn,
      slideUp: !fallIn
    });
  };

  getSkillData = () => {
    const { skills } = this.props;
    const { shownSkill } = this.state;
    return skills[shownSkill];
  };

  render() {
    const { name, skill, description } = this.getSkillData();
    const { shownSkill, slideUp } = this.state;
    const { skills } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="route-container skills">
        <div className="skills-content-container">
          {slideUp ? (
            <div className="skills-right-content slide-up">
              <div className="subtitle">{name}</div>
              {description.map((p, i) => (
                <div className="text" key={i}>
                  {p}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="skills-right-content
            fall-in">
              <div className="subtitle">{name}</div>
              {description.map((p, i) => (
                <div className="text" key={i}>
                  {p}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Skills;
```

Then I am animating the `.fall-in` class with css:

```
@keyframes fall-in {
  0% {
    margin-top: -600px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

.fall-in {
  animation-name: fall-in;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

I would like this animation to trigger once every time the content of the `.subtitle` and `.text` divs changes, regardless of whether or not the animation changed.

This example will only trigger the animation the first time the css class is added.

Comment: From your question, it sounds like react-transition-group component can handle your animations. https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable.

Comment: I guess...But I am building a webpage with react-static and would like to keep the bundle size as small as possible, so I'm looking for another solution - basically trying to figure out a hack how to make react re-render the DOM

Comment: If your goal is to have React re-render the DOM, you can change add or remove a className or something else via setState  to force a re-render on change. Are the .subtitle and .text divs coming from state or is the user entering it? I can't picture what your application is doing but it sounds interesting.

Comment: Basically they are coming from a CMS that react-static passes as props. It's a portfolio - the component is switching between the different CV skills, and animating the text. The thing is, that even though the content of the div (`subtitle`, `text`) is changing, the DOM node itself does not re-render, so the class only gets applied once (not triggering the animation)

Comment: Have you checked out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414308/updating-state-on-props-change-in-react-form which discusses using componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) to update your state based on props changing? It's an old post and may be outdated, but it seems similar to your needs.

Comment: Keys are a great way to force-rerender and apply a keyframe animation again. If you want to change on every content change you can set your key to the content or number of changes. If you provide a working sandbox, could probably help you out more.

Answer (score 0):

Hey maybe you want to give a try on my OSS.

https://github.com/bluebill1049/react-simple-animate

I think it does what you want above, maybe worth to give it a try?

```
import Animate from 'react-simple-img';
import React from 'react';

export default ({ready}) => {
   return <Animate startAnimation={ready} startStyle={{
       marginTop: '-600px',
   }} endStyle={{
       marginTop: '0',
   }}>
       <YourComponent />
   </Animate>
};
```