# React - Passing props from Array to Div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a more complex example of **passing props** from a component to another. In this case, it's the content of an array(when I click on that content) to a `<div>`.

You can find the code here: **https://codesandbox.io/s/509j5npkwx**

**(Please check the code in the link above)**

**TextBox** `<div>` **component**:

```
export class TextBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: "Select A Node To See Its Data Structure Here..."
    };
    this.changeContent = this.changeContent.bind(this);
  }

  changeContent(newContent) {
    this.setState({
      content: newContent
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="padd_top">
        <div className="content_box">{this.state.content}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TextBox;
```

**FileTree component:**

```
export class FileTree extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeNode: null
    }
    this.setActiveNode = this.setActiveNode.bind(this)
  }

  setActiveNode(name) {
    this.setState({ activeNode: name })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="padd_top">{
        renderTree(
          this.props.root || root,
          this.setActiveNode,
          this.state.activeNode
        )
      }
      <TextBox />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm trying to do something like this, for further understanding: **http://alexcurtis.github.io/react-treebeard/**

I understood how to prepare the `<div>` to receive new information, by substituting the "Select A Node To See Its Data Structure Here..." when I click one of the elements belonging to the file tree.

I also understood how to prepare the file tree to pass content `<div>`, but in this case, I'm confused about where and how should I apply to the right component.

**I'm new to React JS.** If you have any tips for me about this issue, I'm very grateful.

Thank you.

---

I changed a bit the structure of my project, and now I'm looking forward to put `<TextBox>` and `<FileTree>` side by side.

More specifically, like this:

```
export class App extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="col-md-12">
            <SearchEngine />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <FileTree />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <TextBox content={this.props.activeNode} />
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
}
```

I tought it wouldn't be different to pass `props` to `<App>`, but again I might be missing something, because it's not passing properly. What is missing here?

Thanks again.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're confused about how to pass the object of the clicked directory/file to the textBox component?

Comment: @DevinFields Exactly. Before I made this example right here, so I could get further understanding: https://codesandbox.io/s/8pkl8w6xy0

Comment: This question may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414308/updating-state-on-props-change-in-react-form?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

also this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: basically, add a prop to textBox: <TextBox propHere="whatever you name it"/>

Then use getDerivedStateFromProps to compare the current and new prop coming in and setState if it is different.

Comment: @DevinFields Hm, okay I think I understand. In this case, I should apply `getDerivedStateFromProps ` inside the `<File>`, yes?

Comment: In the future please put any relevant code in the question as external links can be removed.

Comment: @Jhecht Okay! Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question.

Here is my fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/50pv75q8ll

Basically, you pass the activeNode to < TextBox />. Look at line 126 of index.js.

And then, in text_box.js use componentWillReceiveProps() to set the TextBox state with the content prop. Line 18 of text_box.js.

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` is more up to date as `componentWillReceiveProps` will get deprecated

Comment: It's exactly what you provided, but instead of ./lib/greeting.rb, it's something like this { type: "directory", name: "./lib", contents: [{ type: "file", name: "./lib/greeting.rb" }] } I'm looking to pass to TextBox @Marco Afonso